# What is the general architecture of a server for a game like rust/minecraft?

Tags: client-server

If a game's client is written in Unity or UE4 or another engine, is the server usually written in the same engine? Or is it written in standalone c++?

Does the server use a database like MySQL to store the locations of deployed structures and bases etc? Or is everything stored in memory in arrays or in another way?

Comment: As Philipp mentions below, different games make different decisions. If you can tell us more about *your* game project specifically, we can help you meet your game's particular needs within your working situation. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck or finding trouble?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one solution. It depends on the requirements of your game.

Some game engines offer server components, but I have seen games where the dev team decided that these do not fulfill their requirements, so they wrote their own and communicate with it using the low-level networking features of their engine. Note that client and server don't necessarily need to use the same programming language. My last multiplayer game used a client written in JavaScript (HTML5) and a server written in Java.

Regarding storage: When your game is played in rounds of a few minutes each, you can often do without any persistence on the gameserver and keep everything in memory. But if your game has a persistent game world, you want some form of data storage on hard drive so you can resume the game when the server needs to shut down (or crashes). I have once worked on a game where the gameserver handled a small persistent world using flatfiles. It didn't work *well*, but it worked. But if you have a large number of players, you want to store any information about offline players in a proper database to allow faster login times and ensure data consistency.